# apply nobr html tag to django form fields

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am styling django form fields with this [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template).

form:

```
class contact(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    middle_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
```

template:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% include "form_snippet.html" %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

In form_snippet.html:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In css:

```
.fieldWrapper{
    font-size; 10px;
    color: #f00;
    font-family: verdana, tahoma, serif;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

When I run server, each form field is shown in new line.

I want to have these three form fields in same line instead each in new line.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update css code like this,

```
 .fieldWrapper{
   font-size; 10px;
   color: #f00;
   font-family: verdana, tahoma, serif;
   white-space:nowrap;
   display:inline;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping each field in a `div` tag, a block element.

Give the `.fieldWrapper` class a non block positioning.. like `inline`, `float:left`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As div is a block element, hence putting div tag outer to 'for' loop works:

```
 <div class="fieldWrapper"> 
 {% for field in form %}
         {{ field.errors }}
         {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
 {% endfor %} 
 </div>
```

or
without adding a external css class:

```
 {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        <nobr> {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}</nobr>
 {% endfor %}
```